# What Does "require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)" do Exactly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been trying to understand Ruby on a deeper level, and deconstructing a boiler-plate rails app, seemed like a good way to understand some of the niceties and elegance of writing a Ruby app that spans different files and directories.

In my current app, the dependency on the 'requires' between files is becomming slightly problematic (I'm finding I need to do things like `requires '../../../lib/helper'` and its getting a bit ugly.

I noticed that rails apps don't seem to suffer from this.

I did notice the line:

```
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
```

And when I Google it I find lots of explanation about the Rails boot-up routine, etc, but no clear description about what that line DOES exactly.

In my travels, I've also come along this line:

```
$:.push File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__))
```

I've been wondering if somehow these might be a potential solution to my problem.  Can anyone please explain what they **do** exactly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`__FILE__` is the relative path to the file from current directory. `File.expand_path` will get you absolute path of file, so above in your question require the `environment.rb` file. 
`$:` contains the array of required path, so `$:.push` append the your given path into list of required path, so that you can require that file in your app. Rails push various file while booting process.

Comment: `__FILE__` is not a relative path, it simply returns the file name in which the code resides.

Answer (score 1):

`File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)` returns absolute path of the file environment.rb, which is located in the 'config' directory that is two levels below the file that contains this code.

`require` then gives you access to the ruby code defined in the file environment.rb.